# Importing csv data with multiple trials and creating scatter plot

Tags: python, csv

So, sorry if there's any misconceptions, I have nearly no experience coding.
I have a csv file with 30 data sets, each containing 5 ordered values. I need to create a scatter plot with an x-axis of 1-5 (order of values) vs the value in each data set (thirty y-values per x-value). I've been trying to work off of some example code that was provided, but I'm not really getting anywhere (the example code is for a different data set that isn't similar to what we have) and I don't know what other options there are.

To import the data, I have:

```
data = np.loadtxt('(omitted).csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=1+2, usecols=range(1,6))
```

to attempt to load the data from the csv file. using the excel format, I needed to omit rows 1 and 2, and column A so that it only loaded the raw data. if i print(data), it appears to display correctly.

The next step in the example code was to label columns (in the example they were distance, time etc). Right now, I have labelled each column as its order:

```
throwone = data[:,0];
throwtwo = data[:,1];
throwthree = data[:,2];
throwfour = data[:,3];
throwfive = data[:,4];
```

At this point, the rest of the code isn't very well explained or relevant to our data set. It uses matplotlib; a few of the unexplained lines are:

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
```

I'm fine with labelling x and y-axes, putting limits on the axes as that all makes sense. I'm just lost on how I can plot the data properly so that each x-value has all 30 corresponding y-values.

This is everything I have so far:

```
#import modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#load data
data = np.loadtxt('(omitted).csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=1+2, usecols=range(1,6))

#print(data)  #ensure data looks to be imported correctly
#label columns
throwone = data[:,0];
throwtwo = data[:,1];
throwthree = data[:,2];
throwfour = data[:,3];
throwfive = data[:,4];

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()

plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Test appears blank right now, I'm guessing that means I have to do something specific to add the data to the plot but I'm lost on what to do.

If it makes any difference, I'm using python 3.6 in spyder from Anaconda

Comment: i think pandas would do the task simpler,     pd.read_csv('csv_file', other_parameters_as_per_the_requirements)

Answer (score 0):

`plt` is for creating plots.

You first need to define a plot.

It can be confusing at first in python because with matplotlib you are just issuing commands and not assigning a variable to anything.

for a scatter plot it is as follows

```
plt.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.5)
```

to test before saving loads of files you can print to screen using

```
plt.show()
```

please check here for more guidance.

https://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html

and more detail here:

https://plot.ly/matplotlib/scatter/

Also a great free interactive tutorial here:

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/matplotlib-tutorial-python

As for creating multiple axis for the plot try this:

```
y = [1, 2]
x = [throwone, throwfive, throwfour, throwthree, throwtwo]

for xn, yn in zip(x, y):
    plt.scatter([yn] * len(xn), xn)

plt.xticks([1, 2])
plt.axes().set_xticklabels(['Value1', 'Value2'])
```